# Find all $x,y,z\in \mathbb Z^+$ s.t. $(x+y)^{2022}=(\sqrt{xy})^z$ with $\gcd(z,2022)=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

Let $x,y,z$ be positive integers, find all $x,y,z$ such that $$(x+y)^{2022}=(\sqrt{xy})^z$$
with $\gcd (z,2022)=1$.

This is a math olympiad problem, [here](https://elmaths.com/%D8%A3%D9%88%D9%84%D9%85%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%B6%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%AA-2023-%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%B61-%D8%A3%D9%88%D9%84%D9%89-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%83-%D8%B9%D8%B1/) is the link if you want to check it out.

This is my attempt

$$(x+y)^{2022}=(\sqrt{xy})^z \implies (x+y)^{4044}=(xy)^z.$$
since $(x+y)^a\equiv x^a+y^a\pmod{xy}$, we get $$x^{4044}+y^{4044}\equiv 0 \pmod{xy}$$

I don't know what to do after this.

Comment: You do not get $x\mid y$ and $y\mid x$. You get $x\mid y^{4044}$ and $y\mid x^{4044}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't forget the parentheses; the given relation is equivalent to
$$(x+y)^{4044}=(xy)^z.$$

Now because $z$ is coprime to $2022$, it is coprime to $4044$, and so $xy=w^{4044}$ for some positive integer $w$. Of course then we have $x+y=w^z$. In particular, since $(x+y)^2>xy$ we see that $z>2022$. Then from the identity
$$w^{4044}=xy=x(w^z-x),$$
which we can view as a quadratic equation with integral root $x$, we find that the discriminant
$$\Delta=w^{2z}-4w^{4044}=w^{4044}\big((w^{z-2022})^2-4\big),$$
is a perfect square. But then also
$$(w^{z-2022})^2-4,$$
is a perfect square, which can only happen if $w=2$ and $z=2023$, corresponding to $x=y=2^{2022}$

Comment: I don't quite understand the change in variables that you did with $w$.

Comment: see the edit that I did.

Comment: The first identity shows that $(xy)^z$ is a $4044$-th power of an integer. Because $z$ is coprime to $4044$, it follows that $xy$ is a $4044$th power of an integer. I call this integer $w$.